# JqGrid: how to remove the separator bar in the pager area?

Tags: jqgrid

My grid has just a few rows. There is no page navigation in the pager area. There are only two icon buttons (edit and delete, in this order) on the left side of the pager area. However, on the right side of the delete button, there is a vertical separator bar close to it. I want to remove it.

I am unable to find a way to do this. I also tried CSS hack, but no success.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It seems that you have some CSS conflicts. You should post the demo which reproduce the problem, describe CSSs and frameworks which you currently use and the corresponding version information. The current text contains almost no implementation details which could be used to localize described problem.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for alerting me on the CSS conflicts. Because of it, I got this fixed!!!